# Add custom sub tab under contextual library tools tab in ribbon

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, ribbon, custom-actions

I want to create copy paste functions for document library in SharePoint 2010 
I want to create it as a new custom sub tab under library Tools.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you.
It is a farm solution that permit to copy element of a list.
The button copy is in the ribbon tab.
[image]
[SP List Item Copy enables a user to copy SharePoint list items. User can use this feature easily via Ribbon UI](https://splistkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SP%20List%20Item%20Copy).

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers, try to include the main steps in your post and use the link as a reference to the details.